# Determine the discontinuities of the following function

Tags: real-analysis

Determine the discontinuities of the following function:

$$ f(x) =  \cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) , \ \ x<0\\ $$
$$f(x)= x^2,  \ \ 0 \leq x \leq 1$$ 
$$  f(x)=\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x-2} , \ \ 1<x<2 $$ 
$$ f(x) =2 , \ \ x=2 $$ 
$$ f(x) =\sqrt{x-1} , \ \ x>2  $$

For each discontinuity identified above, classify whether the discontinuity are removable, jump discontinuity, infinite or oscillating.

**Answer:**

From the definition of the function, we see that;

The functions $ \ f(x) \ $ has discontinuities at $ \ x=0, \ x=1, \ x=2 \ $

Among this,

$ x=2 \ $ is removable singularity, jump discontinuity.

$x=1 \ $ is jump discontinuity.

$x=0 \ $ is infinite discontinuity.

Does this seem to be correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems so

Comment: Your answer for $x=0$ is wrong. It is an oscillating discontinuity since $\cos (\frac 1 x)$ oscillates as $x \to 0-$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $f(0^-)$ does not exist, as the function is oscillating.
- $f(0)=f(0^+)=0$.

Hence oscillating.

- $f(1^-)=f(0)=1$.
- $f(1^+)=0$.

Hence jump.

- $f(2^-)=1$ (you can simplify by $x-2$).
- $f(2)=2$.
- $f(2^+)=1$.

Hence removable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**At $x=0$, it is oscillatory discontinuity but *not* infinite discontinuity.**
         It is oscillatory discontinuity because here, for$\ \ x<0 , \cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) $ appear to be approaching many values simultaneously as $x \to 0^-$.

**Infinite discontinuity** means the function goes to infinity at that point. Both Left Hand Limit and Right Hand Limit are not finite.

**At $x=1$, it is jump discontinuity.** The function is approaching different values depending on the direction x is coming from. As  $x \to 1^-$, $f(x) \to 1 $ and $x \to 1^+$, $f(x) \to 0 $.

**At $x=2$, it is a removable singularity but *not* jump discontinuity.** 
At jump discontinuity, LHL $\neq$ RHL. But here they are equal.